# Why Am I Unable to Pass Data to Iron-Router Route Template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I just updated to Meteor 1.0 and the latest version of Iron-Router.

For whatever reason, when I pass data to a template that includes only a single document, it works. But when I try to pass multiple documents to the template, I get a blank screen.

```
//galleryRoute.js

Router.route('/:section', function() {
    this.layout('Gallery', {
        data: function() { 
            var data =  { photos: photos.find({ path: { $regex: '/'+this.params.section +'/' } }) };
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
<template name="Gallery">
    <div class="container">
        {{#each photos}}    
            <div class="section-photo" style="background:url({{path}}) no-repeat center center; width:175px; height:175px; background-size:cover;"></div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

---

Wondering if anyone has any ideas about why this would be?

Comment: Is your `.find()` returning anything? Try fetching the results of your `.find()` and logging the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824800/meteor-data-passed-to-template-from-iron-router-is-empty-at-first-load

Answer (score -1):

In your data function, you're accessing `this.params.section`. However, `this` is refers to your current scope, which is not the route, therefore `this.params` will be undefined. Try doing something like this:

```
//galleryRoute.js

Router.route('/:section', function() {
    var route = this;
    this.layout('Gallery', {
        data: function() { 
            var data =  { photos: photos.find({ path: { $regex: '/'+route.params.section +'/' } }) };
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The Iron Router documentation explicitly says that you should access route parameters by referencing `this.params` in [this section](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-parameters).

Comment: Your example is different, because you are trying to access the `params` property of `this` in a new scope, the scope of your lambda function assigned to the `data` property. Outside of that function, in the parent scope, `this.params` will work just fine.