# Meteor: data passed to template from Iron Router, is empty at first load

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm facing a strange problem.
I'm using Iron Router controller to pass data to template:

```
Router.route('/wards/add/:_id?', {name: 'wards.add', controller: 'WardAddController'});

    WardAddController = RouteController.extend({
      action: function() {
        this.render('addWard', { 
          data: function(){
            return { hospitals : Hospitals.find({}), hospital_id : this.params._id }
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

I return a variable 'hospitals', that should contain all the collection data.
Template:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    {{#each hospitals}}
        {{name}}<br>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

At first page load, if I type the directly the url of the page, there are no items.
If I type Hospitals.find({}).fetch() (insecure is active) in the browser console, it return an empty object.

But if i change pages, navigating on the website a while, and return the the listing page, items appears.

Any idea?

Comment: How big is the Hospitals collection? Have you tried using iron router's waitOn function?

Comment: Right now the collection have a couple of element. I would use wait on if I had to subscribe, but here the data is passed directly to template!

Comment: Do you still have autopublish added?

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes.

Comment: Just checked, I do not have autopublish package. Just insecure package.

Comment: Do you have another route that subscribes to a publication of the Hospitals collection?

Comment: Yes, the subscription is in the onCreated function of another template.

Comment: It makes sense then that the client doesn't have the data until you've accessed that other template. Add a waitOn for that subscription to this route and it won't be empty when you navigate directly to it.

Comment: I think it make no sense, the routes are separated. In this template, I'm getting the data from the router not with a subscription!

Comment: Since you don't have autopublish, the client won't have the data unless there's a subscription. Setting the data context is not the same thing.

Comment: Then, if i would to pass data to template, the only way is pub/sub?

Comment: Same problem if I get hospitals list, from a template helper.
Strange situation.

Comment: @PieroMaltese if you are not using autopublish then yes you need to use pub/sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server folder, add publish.js and inside it add:

```
Meteor.publish('hospitals', function() {
  return Hospitals.find({});
});
```

Then try subscribing to hospitals from your controller:

```
WardAddController = RouteController.extend({
  action: function() {
    this.render('addWard', { 
      waitOn: function() {
        return [
              Meteor.subscribe('hospitals')
           ];
      },
      data: function(){
        return { hospitals : Hospitals.find({}), hospital_id : this.params._id }
      }
    });
  }
});
```